# ng-option select with extra data-binding?

Tags: angularjs

I've tried to google (a lot) to find an answer to this, but i'm kinda lost for the *right* keywords, so forgive me the flimsy attempt to give this post a proper title...

please refer to [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9ntoavj/9/) to get a clearer picture of what I'm trying to do.

my question is: can i possibly update the display of the fullname-filter in the select-option, if either 'firstname'-, 'lastname'-fields (or both) change?

*okay-okay*: i need to be more precise: i know my approach doesn't quite cut it (yet) ;-) , but maybe there is a way that someone likes to share, or point me in the direction of?

thanks in advance, 
s.

**HTML:**

```
<label for="userPick">User: </label>
<select name="userPick" ng-selected="input.user.id" ng-model="input.user" ng-options="oUser as ( oUser | fullnamefilter ) for oUser in output.user track by oUser.id">
    <option value="">Select User</option>
</select>

<div ng-show="control.showUser">
    <h4>id: {{input.user.id}}</h4>  
        <label for="userShort">Short: </label>
        <input name="userShort" type="text" value="{{input.user.short}}" ng-model="input.user.short" /> 
                            <br/>
        <label for="user1stName">First Name: </label>
        <input name="user1stName" type="text" value="{{input.user.firstname}}" ng-model="input.user.firstname" />
                            <br/>
        <label for="userLastName">Last Name: </label>
        <input name="userLastName" type="text" value="{{input.user.lastname}}" ng-model="input.user.lastname" />

                            <br/>                                 
</div>
```

**FILTER:**

```
var App = angular.module( 'io_module', [] ) ;

App.filter('fullnamefilter', function(){
    return function(x) {
        return x.firstname + " " + x.lastname ;
    }
}) ;
```

in **Controller:**

```
$scope.output = {
    user: [{
                id:1,
                short:"bb",
                vorname:"billie",
                lastname:"bobb"
            },
            {
                id:2,
                short:"dc",
                firstname:"dweezil",
                name:"cummings"
            }],
    ...
} ;


$scope.input = {
    user: {
                id:null,
                short:null,
                firstname:null,
                lastname:null
            },
    ...
} ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$track by` with `select as` in `ng-options`.

As [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) say:

> but this will not work:
>   
>   $scope.selected = $scope.items[0].subItem;
>   In both examples, the track by expression is applied successfully to each item in the items array. Because the selected option has been set programmatically in the controller, the track by expression is also applied to the ngModel value. In the first example, the ngModel value is items[0] and the track by expression evaluates to items[0].id with no issue. In the second example, the ngModel value is items[0].subItem and the track by expression evaluates to items[0].subItem.id (which is undefined). As a result, the model value is not matched against any  and the  appears as having no selected value.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/0jk0g0yr/).

```js
var App = angular.module( 'io_module', [] ) ;

App.filter('userfilter', function(){
    return function(x) {
        return x.firstname + " " + x.lastname ;
    }
}) ;

App.controller( 'ioController', [ '$scope', '$log', function( $scope, $log ){    
    $scope.control = {
        showUser:true
    } ;
  $scope.output = {
      user: [{
                  id:1,
                  short:"bb",
                  firstname:"billie",
                  lastname:"bobb"
              },
              {
                  id:2,
                  short:"dc",
                  firstname:"dweezil",
                  lastname:"cummings"
              }]
  } ;


  $scope.input = {
      user: {
                  id:null,
                  short:null,
                  firstname:null,
                  lastname:null
              }
  } ;
}]) ;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="io_module">

 <div ng-controller="ioController"> 
   <label for="userPick">User: </label>
   <select name="userPick" ng-selected="input.user.id" ng-model="input.user" ng-options="oUser as ( oUser | userfilter ) for oUser in output.user">
      <option value="">Select User</option>
  </select>

  <div ng-show="control.showUser">
      <h4>id: {{input.user.id}}</h4>  
          <label for="userShort">Short: </label>
          <input name="userShort" type="text" value="{{input.user.short}}" ng-model="input.user.short" /> 
                              <br/>
          <label for="user1stName">First Name: </label>
          <input name="user1stName" type="text" value="{{input.user.firstname}}" ng-model="input.user.firstname" />
                              <br/>
          <label for="userLastName">Last Name: </label>
          <input name="userLastName" type="text" value="{{input.user.lastname}}" ng-model="input.user.lastname" />

                              <br/>                                 
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: okay...THAT nails it! short, sweet and right to the point. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use ngKeyup to capture model change values

```
 <label for="user1stName">First Name: </label>
          <input name="user1stName" type="text" value="{{input.user.firstname}}" ng-model="input.user.firstname" ng-keyup="keyupFuncton(input)"/>
                              <br/>
          <label for="userLastName">Last Name: </label>
          <input name="userLastName" type="text" value="{{input.user.lastname}}" ng-model="input.user.lastname" ng-keyup="keyupFuncton(input)" />
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.keyupFuncton = function(newData) {        
  angular.forEach($scope.output.user, function(out, index){       
      if (out.id == newData.user.id) {            
         $scope.output.user[index] = newData.user;  

      }
  })
  };
```

[Edited your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7c65f4dL/)

Comment: i appreciate your effort, but I don't get it, and your fiddle doesnot work for me either... As a matther of fact Stepan Kasyanenko's answer below is the answer i was looking for. it fixes an apparent misconception of mine which blocked proper 2-way binding from working. simple, easy straight to the point!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so hopefully this will make it easier, without losing the functionality you want....

You can use the ngChange directive on the input tag.  This will call the function you pass it anytime the user types or removes a character.

```
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text"  
       ng-model="userInput.firstname" 
       ng-change="adjustedFilterSearch()"/>

<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text"  
       ng-model="userInput.lastname" 
       ng-change="adjustedFilterSearch()"/>
{{ searchResults | json }}
```

This will call the function in the controller, which you can use to wrap a filter.  Filters need at least two arguments, the data you are searching, and some criteria.  Luckily, you can just pass it the userInput object from the ngModel, and angular will suss out the properties.

```
$scope.searchResults;
$scope.adjustedFilterSearch = function() {
    $scope.searchResults = $filter('filter')($scope.users, $scope.userInput)
};
```

I would recommend stripping out all the extra attributes and directives until you get the basic functionality working first.  Also, your objects in the controller look more complicated than they need to be.  Why not just start with:

```
$scope.users = [
    {firstname: "Clark", lastname: "Kent"},
    {firstname: "Bruce", lastname: "Wayne"}
};
```

which is going to be much easier to iterate over or filter through. Once you can conceptualize and implement this, then you can build out your objects with nested objects *if it's even necessary.*  Here's [the simplified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChildeRowland/ptkhq8nv/#&togetherjs=rLmAlKm9pr).